# Fetching content from 3rd pary site in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-views

I have website, and i need to fetch content from some pages on another site. How do i do this with drupal7 and probably views?

Comment: What type of content do you want to fetch? HTML / RSS / RDF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Parser 2 module for drupal

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you want to store the content in a node or not, you will want to use one of these modules: Aggregator, Feeds, Aggregator2 or Leech.

Detailed description of these modules can be found [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/3418).